# Spring Boot (using tomcat) url redirect no template engine

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot for my web service & web app. Now i wan't my web server to automatically redirect from ex. www.mypage.com:8080  to www.mapage.com:8080/index.html.

I don't want to use any template engine like Thymeleaf, so i cannot do this by @RequestMapping in controller because returning String by method using @RequestMapping will actually print that string as text and not fetch file and render it.

I've also made root url + suffix (ex. www.mypage.com:8080/page2.html) to use resources/templates directory as source by adding ".addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/", "classpath:/templates/")". After this manually entering www.mypage.com:8080/index.html or www.mypage.com:8080/page2.html will show the correct page.

So I'm asking is there a way to map www.mypage.com to mypage.com/index.html and still have other pages like www.mypage.com:8080/page2.html work, that is root page (/) to still look in resources/templates dir?
Maybe redirection or something will help (using tomcat 7 with spring boot)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use template engine so I assume your HTML files are static files. In order to achieve your goal, put HTML files into directory `src/main/resources/static/`. In your case, put file `index.html` to this folder and it becomes immediately available just by calling `http://<domain>/index.html`.

To make redirection to this file from `http://<domain>/` create controller like that:

```java
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String index(){
        return "redirect:/index.html";
    }    
}
```

No other changes like adding resources handlers are required.

Comment: did not work for me, not sure why but this redirection did not work
i've made resource handlers because using resources/static did not work for my js & css in past (i've kept only these in static) so i've mapped static & templates just to get it done

i've also created REST service in this app so maybe there's some kind of conflict between them - i'm using spring rest & spring web mvc

anyway thank you for clearing some stuff up how they work in spring

Answer (score 0):

Please do:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class RedirectController {

    @GetMapping("/forwardWithForwardPrefix")
    public ModelAndView redirectWithUsingForwardPrefix() {
        return new ModelAndView("forward:/redirectedUrl");
    }
}
```